AWK sorting function: the l and r parameters, what are they really about?
In AWK, in order to sort an array, I can define my own sorting function, both to control the traversal of an array in a for loop, or to call asort or asorti. The signature of the comparison function accepts up to 6 parameters, although the last two are optional:
function cmp_field(i1, v1, i2, v2, l, r) { whatever; }

What are the purpose of l and r? As I understand, they are just placeholders that are not used or inspected by AWK at all, but rather a convenience for myself so that I can store values inside them, as some sort of convenience helper variables. Like assigning in l and r temporary values calculated from v1 and v2. However, why do I need them or what's its purpose, if I can just declare my own variables like:
function cmp_field(i1, v1, i2, v2) { 
   l = computation(v1);
   r = computation(v2);
   whatever; 
}

Is there any other difference besides l and r being global variables in the second example? Or is there any other reasons besides that?

Function parameters are local. Other variables are global.
From the specification:

Variables and Special Variables
Variables can be used in an awk program by referencing them. With the exception of function parameters (see User-Defined Functions ), they are not explicitly declared. Function parameter names shall be local to the function; all other variable names shall be global. The same name shall not be used as both a function parameter name and as the name of a function or a special awk variable. The same name shall not be used both as a variable name with global scope and as the name of a function. The same name shall not be used within the same scope both as a scalar variable and as an array. Uninitialized variables, including scalar variables, array elements, and field variables, shall have an uninitialized value. An uninitialized value shall have both a numeric value of zero and a string value of the empty string. Evaluation of variables with an uninitialized value, to either string or numeric, shall be determined by the context in which they are used.

and:

User-Defined Functions
The awk language also provides user-defined functions. Such functions can be defined as:
function name([parameter, ...]) { statements }
A function can be referred to anywhere in an awk program; in particular, its use can precede its definition. The scope of a function is global.
The number of parameters in the function definition need not match the number of parameters in the function call. Excess formal parameters can be used as local variables. If fewer arguments are supplied in a function call than are in the function definition, the extra parameters that are used in the function body as scalars shall evaluate to the uninitialized value until they are otherwise initialized, and the extra parameters that are used in the function body as arrays shall be treated as uninitialized arrays where each element evaluates to the uninitialized value until otherwise initialized.


Ok so the presence of l and r is not something specific of the sorting function, but rather I can define as many extra parameters as I wish in AWK function signatures to use as purely local variables, is that right?

@ABu yes, that's right

there is a convention that local variables are separared from expected parameters by extra whitespace. eg. function cmp_field(i1, v1, i2, v2,         l, r) {. Note that not cuddling the brace changes the meaning of the program.

yes ty for the reminder. I have modified the question to fix the braces.

@abu actually, I think I'm wrong. the function keyword lets awk know that the brace is the definition, not a separate action, although not cuddling can affect other code

All variables in awk are GLOBAL unless used in a function signature. Therefor, if you use l and r inside of cmp_field it will change the value of l and r globally unless it is part of the function signature.
If you add the variables that you use inside your function, even if not used when calling your function, those become local to that function. The convention is to do something along the lines of:
function cmp_field(i1, v1, i2, v2,       l, r) { 
                    #             ^ ^ ^   by convention, spaces
                    # indicates l,r and not used in the function call
                    # the values of i1, v1, i2, v2, l, r are LOCAL now
                    # whatever
}

Consider this example:
seq 3 | awk '
function f1(a,       b,c) {
    #                ^ ^   now local to f1
    a=b=c=a*2
    return a
}

function f2(a) {
    a=b=c=a*2
    # ^ ^           GLOBAL. Will change b,c but not a
    return a
}

{   
    a=b=c=1
    printf("a=%s, b=%s, c=%s, $1=%s, f1($1)=%s, a=%s, b=%s, c=%s\n",a,b,c, $1, f1($1),a,b,c)
    printf("a=%s, b=%s, c=%s, $1=%s, f2($1)=%s, a=%s, b=%s, c=%s\n\n",a,b,c, $1, f2($1),a,b,c)
}'

Prints:
a=1, b=1, c=1, $1=1, f1($1)=2, a=1, b=1, c=1
a=1, b=1, c=1, $1=1, f2($1)=2, a=1, b=2, c=2

a=1, b=1, c=1, $1=2, f1($1)=4, a=1, b=1, c=1
a=1, b=1, c=1, $1=2, f2($1)=4, a=1, b=4, c=4

a=1, b=1, c=1, $1=3, f1($1)=6, a=1, b=1, c=1
a=1, b=1, c=1, $1=3, f2($1)=6, a=1, b=6, c=6


to be safe, you might need  more sequence points. I'm not sure if it is defined what order parameters are expanded (so it might be implementation-defined whether the printf b is the value before or after the f2 call)

but regardless: awk 'function f(a){return b=a+1} BEGIN{a=b=0; print a,b,f(a); a=b=0; print a,f(a),b}'

@jhnc so it might be implementation-defined whether the printf b is the value before or after the f2 call) : my best interpretation of the 2024 POSIX awk spec is that value of b shouldn't be implementation defined at all - f2($1) must complete its function call, inc. alteration of global variables, & return, before s/printf() is allowed to evaluate the next expr argument (or obtain its value). I believe the print out by @dawg is accurate. nawks occasionally use stale values, but that's a major bug in nawk instead of spec saying implementation deviation is permissible.

This also isn't a case about operator precedence in expressions - commas serve a very limited but clearly defined role - delineating lists of expressions / patterns (as in the pattern range pairing) / function call parameters. The spec mandates a sequential evaluation of list items, and that the same items appearing more than once along the list must be re-evaluated each time, to ensure stale values from prior evaluations do not cascade downstream. The comma operator isn't listed on the precedence table because it's not an operator for any expression.
